# Displaying a "No rows found" message in UITableView with Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have implemented an iPhone app that uses UITableViewController/UITableView and Core Data.  Further, I use a NSFetchedResultsController to manage the table data.  This was all very straight forward and works great. I then decided that I should display a message in the UITableView when no rows where found/retrieved.  After researching this, it appeared that the best way (perhaps the only way) to do this was to return a "dummy" cell that contains the message.  However, when I do this, I get a nastygram from the runtime system that complains (and rightfully so) about data inconsistencies: "Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view ...".  Here is the relevant code:

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0) return 1;
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0) return 1;
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex: section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] == 0) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No widgets found.";
        return cell;
    }

    STCellView *cell = (STCellView *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"ShieldCell"];
    [self configureCell: cell atIndexPath: indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

I have read responses from similar questions and it appears that I should use

```
insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:
```

to insert the "dummy" message row into my table.  However, this also means removing the "dummy" row when a real row is inserted.  I can do this, but it seems like there should be an easier way to accomplish this.  All I want to do, is to display a message indicating that there are no rows in the table (simple enough?).  So, my question is this:  Is there a way to display a message in an UITableView without using the "dummy" cell approach OR is there a way to convince UITableViewController/NSFetchResulsController that this is only a "dummy" row and they should not get so upset about it because it is not a real row (from my point of view) in the table?

Any help you can provide would be very appreciated (I am a struggling newbie to iPhone development and I want to learn the best practices).  Thanks.

Comment: Rather than hack with the tableview datasource to get the intended UI why not add the "No rows found" message to the tableview header instead?

Comment: This is the best approach if you only have one section in your table view. See my approach below for multiple sections

Comment: @Rog This was the perfect answer.  In viewWillAppear, I load a table view header if the row count is 0.  Unfortunately, because you did not enter this as an answer, I cannot select it, but it is (in my opinion) the cleanest and best answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks I'm glad it worked for you. I've added it as an answer so others can find it easily in the future so feel free to mark it as correct next time you're around.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than hack with the tableview datasource to get the intended UI you should add the "No rows found" message to the tableview header instead.

Comment: This was the cleanest and best answer. Thanks very much!!

Comment: I like the sound of this. Are you saying that you watch for the number of rows available, then conditionally show/hide the tableview header? Or always show the header and just change its text to "No rows found"?

Comment: Andy - you can use the footer as well.

Comment: If I want to show a full screen image representing "No data found", how can we do that?

Comment: @Satyam What was your work around? I believe I'm having a similar issue as well.

Answer (score 7):

I did as follows in viewDidLoad.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[label setText:@"No widgets found."];
[label sizeToFit];
label.frame = CGRectMake((self.tableView.bounds.size.width - label.bounds.size.width) / 2.0f,
                         (self.tableView.rowHeight - label.bounds.size.height) / 2.0f,
                         label.bounds.size.width,
                         label.bounds.size.height);
[self.tableView insertSubview:label atIndex:0];
```

In this case, each TableViewCells must be opaque to hide the label. or need to toggle the hidden property of the label according to the row count.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach, which I have used before is to use Core Data to manage the update for you by inserting a 'no rows' entity for the section where no rows have been detected in your model class, which handles the data update.

There are a number of ways to implement this e.g. set the name/title field to a known status message or a flag within the entity. Once inserted you can detect the 'no rows' entity in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and insert an alternative table cell to show the message.

Just remove the 'no rows' entity before refreshing the data for that section.

Comment: Why the down vote? I was just providing a working solution to handle multiple sections!

Answer (score 1):

My simple suggestion to display an empty message is to rearrange your controller to be a simple `UIViewController` (not a `UITableViewController`).

This `UIViewController` is composed by a `UITableView` (the controller is the data source and the delegate for your table) and by a `UILabel` (or a `UIView` that contains a `UILabel`) that displays the empty row message.

In this manner you can control the visibility of the table and the label based on the retrieved rows.

This approach could be laborious but I think it's good to avoid hacking `NSFetchResultsController` and data source. Furthermore you could have a complete control on arranging the position for your empty message.

As @Rog suggested you could also use the table view header to display that message. As you prefer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not a good solution because you cannot use ``UITableViewController``' built-in ``UIRefreshControl`` properly subclassing ``UIViewController``. It is better to use view controller containment to embed the table view controller subclass and handle the empty view in the container view controller.

Comment: @amb It's a possible solution...the op hasn't requested to use a pull down to refresh functionality...In my opionion here the containment is too much. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right, but using both a ``UITableViewController`` and a ``UIRefreshControl`` is something very common when you have to display an empty table view message.